# I try to relink charts in PowerPoint 2016 to different Excel files

Tags: vba, charts, hyperlink, powerpoint

I'm trying to solve the problem to re-link several shapes in a PowerPoint 2016 presentation to other Excel files than they were originally the sources. (Reproducing what is done by FILE > Information > Edit Links to Files).
What works: relinking Excel tables (with the help of `.Linkformat.SourceFullName`)

What I manage to do with all the charts: Update linked charts with new data - doing "Refresh":

```
Sub ChangeChartData()
Dim pptChart As Chart
    Dim pptChartData As ChartData
    Dim pptWorkbook As Object
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasChart Then
                Set pptChart = shp.Chart
                Set pptChartData = pptChart.ChartData
                pptChartData.Activate
                Set pptWorkbook = pptChartData.Workbook
                On Error Resume Next
                'this is where the miracle should happen
                'some other Workbook should be assigned

                'update first link
                pptWorkbook.UpdateLink pptWorkbook.LinkSources(1)

                On Error GoTo 0
                pptWorkbook.Close True
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Set pptWorkbook = Nothing
    Set pptChartData = Nothing
    Set pptChart = Nothing

End Sub
```

But I, kind of, want to change the linked Workbook - and I do not know how although I tried and searched a lot. There seems to be no way of reassigning the linked Workbook with the help of VBA - is this truly the fact? 
I really would appreciate any help or information.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Katharina

Comment: It looks like you're trying to change the links in PowerPoint chart objects, which are always embedded, not linked. With a bit of fiddling you can force PPT to link the chart worksheet to an external data sheet, but as far as I can tell, that link is not exposed via the OM (or rather there's a property like IsLinked (or similar) but no matching LinkSource property.

Comment: Thank you, Steve, for clarification. So the solution should not be re-linking the chart but finding out how the linked external data sheet could be redirected to a different external data sheet, yes?
Oh my. What a challenge this is - and I expected it to be as easy as it is within the user interface.